# rel_list empty in TinyMCE4

Tags: cakephp, tinymce-4

I'm using TinyMCE (on a CakePHP site, using CakeDC TinyMCE plugin).  I've followed the instructions for adding a rel_list (I want to add Lightbox groups).

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:rel_list

The option for rel shows up in my Link dialog box, however the populated list is empty.

Any thoughts?

```
//<![CDATA[
tinymce.init({
  script : "/TinyMCE/js/tiny_mce/tinymce.min.js",
  load_script : "1",
  selector : "textarea",
  plugins : "image,link,",
  image_advtab : "true",
  rel_list : "[ {title: 'Lightbox', value: 'lightbox'}, {title: 'Lightbox Group A', value: 'lightboxA'},]"
});
```

Comment: If you take a closer look at the example, you'll see that the value for `rel_list` is not a string.

Comment: Ahhhh, okay, I see what you mean...  Unfortunately the plugin pops those quote marks in there automatically - configs are set in my bootstrap.php and then converts - looks like I'm going to have to try and edit the main plugin code...  Thanks!